# Create a procedure with turbodbc

Tags: python, python-3.x, teradata, turbodbc

I'm trying to create procedure on Teradata using turbodbc.
There is my sample code:

```
from turbodbc import connect
con = connect(dsn="Teradata")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("""
create procedure dev.test_procedure (
) sql security invoker 
begin 
    delete dev.test_table;
end;
""")
```

And got this error:

```
DatabaseError: ODBC error
state: 42000
native error code: -3706
message: [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database] Syntax error:
Invalid  SQL Statement.
```

But the same code works with no errors in Teradata SQL Assistant. What's wrong?

Comment: Perhaps using DBQL on the Teradata side to capture the actual incorrect SQL statement text would give a clue as to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution is use teradatasql. This sample works fine:

```
import teradatasql
with teradatasql.connect(
    '{"host":"my_host","user":"my_user","password":"my_password"}'
) as con:
    with con.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute("""
            create procedure dev.test_procedure (
            ) sql security invoker 
            begin 
                delete dev.test_table ; 
            end ; 
            """)
```

But, it will be good if someone knows solution with turbodbc.